# 'PHPUnit_Framework_Error_Warning' with message 'session_regenerate_id(): Cannot regenerate session id - headers already sent'

Tags: php, session, zend-framework, phpunit

I ran into this problem writing controller tests for logging in. I found an answer for the Yii framework but I use Zend. The answer was to use ob_start() but it didn't work for me until I figured out where to put it. I ended up landing on having it at the top of my Bootstrap.php file. If anyone else has figured out a better way of doing this please let me know

Comment: You need to use a session abstraction class. Then mock it during tests

Answer (score 0):

Please try to set:

```
Zend_Session::$_unitTestEnabled = true;
```

In your tests, could work.

Another solution could be to redirect the PHPUnit output, so that it doesn't interrupt the html output.

```
phpunit --stderr controllerTest.php
```

Comment: does anyone knows how to do this in ZF3 ?